# Static javascript variable to be used as counter in Angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, static-variables

I would like to create a static javascript variable to be used as a counter inside a Angularjs controller. This static variable will be used inside a polling function that gets repeatedly called.

I want to use the static variable in a manner that looks like this;

```
var polling_func = function()
{
    static var counter = 0;

    if (counter == 10)
    {
        alert('Do action');
        counter = 0;
    }
    counter = counter + 1;
    $timeout(polling_func, 1000);
}
polling_func();
```

Unfortunately, I cannot declare a static variable using static keyword in javascript. How should I go about doing so in my code?

Comment: In Angular, services are singletons.  So, you could create a `CounterService` that performed this for any controller.  Then, the counter could be part of the service scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not declare a global variable, so it will not change the value whenever function is called.

```
 var counter = 0;
var polling_func = function()
{


    if (counter == 10)
    {
        alert('Do action');
        counter = 0;
    }
    counter = counter + 1;
}
polling_func();
$timeout(polling_func, 1000);
```

Comment: Your solution sounds so simple and workable that I feel like an idiot:) Upvoted. But it does not exactly answer my question, though.

Comment: still I got a down vote.. Anyway i ll explain, this answeris just what op required, he asks whether it is possible to create a static variable, and that's what i ve answered. explaining how to create a service for counter would be out of scope of this question. :)

Comment: Well, I am the OP and I upvoted it. I like the simple solution.

Comment: And I upvoted it, even though I offered another solution as well! I very rarely downvote, unless it really is just wildly off.

Comment: I still prefer the simple solution because I can do it. Chosen your answer as The answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think @Naeem-Shaikh's answer is the simplest one, and pure JS.

But since you flagged angular, there is a more Angular-ish way to do it: use a service.

```
app.factory('Counter',function() {
  return {c:0};
});
```

and then in your controller (or multiple controllers):

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',function(Counter) {
   Counter.counter++;
});
```

factories/services are intended to be long-lived and pass methods and variables around between short-lived controllers.

If all you need is a var (i.e. no methods) like here, there is a short-hand:

```
app.value('Counter',{counter:0});
```

And then use it in controllers in the same way.

Comment: this answer well suites the angular requirements.. nice :)

Comment: I remember in my early days learning Perl, the first thing I learned was, "everything has multiple ways to do it, and multiple are equally valid."

Comment: Although your answer is more correct in the sense that it answers my question more relevantly, I will prefer Naeem-Shaikh's answer because it is one that I can do. Sorry.

Comment: Don't apologize! You pick the best one, and if you have 2, but one suits you better, select the one that best answers and upvote others. By answering here, someone else in a different situations may be able to use it. :-)